# Delphi Mouse Click Coordinates

Tags: delphi

[image]

Hi, i' ve 3 panels consisting of form.
I assigned a click event to 3rd panel to getting coordinates.

```
procedure TformMain.Panel3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  pt : tPoint;
begin
  pt := Mouse.CursorPos;
  ShowMessage('X : ' + IntToStr(pt.X) + ' & Y : ' + IntToStr(pt.Y));
end;
```

This code works, but i don' t know how to Y coord. starting from beginning of the panel 3.
 I mean when i click the panel3' s top, it's y coord must be 0.

Thanks in advice.

p.s. : My form has a main menu, so i tried to subtract panel1 height from the pt.y but i couldnt get main menu's height.

Comment: Something like that `ptFromPanel3 := panel3.ScreenToClient(pt);`?

Comment: yes, i used ScreenToClient and subtract panel1.Height then it works. Thanks all :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you use [OnMouseDown event](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.OnMouseDown) and [OnMouseUp event](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.OnMouseUp).

Instead of `OnClick` event which already provide you with X,Y coordinates of the mouse click/release, not to mention with the information about which mouse button was used and state of special keys like <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and <kbd>ALT</kbd>.

For better explanation of what information these events provide check the [TMouseEvent documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.Controls.TMouseEvent).

Comment: Then I belive it would be even better if you use OnMouseDown and MouseUp events instead of OnClick

Comment: you right buddy, i realized that. Thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

To convert coordinates use `ClientToScreen()` and `ScreenToClient()` methods:

```
procedure TformMain.Panel3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  pt: TPoint;
begin
  // Converting from screen coordinates into Sender (that's Panel3)
  // client area coordinates
  pt := TPanel(Sender).ScreenToClient(Mouse.CursorPos);
  ShowMessage('X : ' + IntToStr(pt.X) + ' & Y : ' + IntToStr(pt.Y));
end;
```